# How to add tabbar controller in navigation based application?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITabBar+UITableviewController in navigation based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761716/uitabbaruitableviewcontroller-in-navigation-based-applications)

I am right now working on a navigation based iPhone application. After completing half of the code, now I need to add tab bar controller in some of the pages.

I would like to mention that my first/home page contains 6 buttons, pressing which different pages are navigated. While the other pages will contain navigation bar at the top, table view in the middle and tab bar with 6 tab bar items in the bottom that help to navigate to different pages. I added the tab bar and the items from the library but don't know how to access them.

Comment: Take a look at [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761716/uitabbaruitableviewcontroller-in-navigation-based-applications/3762086#3762086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these two books by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche - the authors do a great job stepping the readers through a lot of the core information you need to begin iPhone development.

[Exploring iPhone 3 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263) (Amazon)

and "More iPhone 3 Development"